# Dialogflow: How do I get sys.boolean?

Tags: dialogflow-es, boolean-expression, api-ai

I would like to add training phrases like

```
Yes
I would love to
No
No, thanks
```

and extract a boolean var `$extraCheese` containing `True` or `False` which I can use later. If I was expecting a color, I would do `$dressColor` and `@sys.color`, but then I don't find `@sys.boolean`

**How do I do this?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is, indeed, baffling that Dialogflow doesn't offer this natively. They offer this as an option for a [Followup Intent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#follow_up_intents), if that is suitable for you, but not as a System Entity.

Fortunately, it is fairly easy for you to make a `Boolean` [Entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#developer_entities) yourself.

Click on the + sign next to the Entity menu option on the left.

Set the name for the Entity: such as Boolean.

Add the value for an entity (`true` for example) which is the text value your webhook will be sent. You then also add aliases for that value. This needs to include the value itelf (`true`, again), but also anything else the user might say to represent this value (`yes`, `sure`, etc).

Then repeat this for other values you may want.

When you're done, you can click Save and then use this entity in your sample phrases just like the built-in entities.

[image]

Comment: Be careful with using just `if(param)`, since `"false"` is, well... a string.  This solution won't allow to use the variable as intended (a boolean). The mapping would have to be compared to `(param == 'true')` (or `(param != 'false')`, depending on what you trust the most to be caught up correctly)